# Is there a standard "height" (or ordinate) and "width" for a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, normality-assumption

I am trying to understand if/how one might be able to infer standard deviation given only a mean and a sample size (and perhaps the min and max values). I realize that mathematically this is impossible as one needs to know the individual scores of the sample to calculate SD; however, I was wondering if an SD could be *approximated* given the aforementioned information using the same kinds of assumptions we use for the GLM. To that end, I was wondering if there is a standard "form" that makes up a normal distribution. I.e., if an extremely low SD and high mean makes a "tall" and "skinny" normal distribution, and an extremely high SD and low mean makes a "short" and "wide" normal distribution, then is there some description for what shape the "average" normal distribution is (and I don't mean in terms of skewness or kurtosis; I'm referring more to the "height" and "width" of the curve)?

Answer (score 1):

For a sample from a normal distribution, the sample mean $\bar X$
and the sample standard deviation $S$ are independent random variables.
So you can forget about using means to estimate standard deviations.

However, there *is* a rough correspondence between the sample range
and the sample standard deviation. Some elementary texts even suggest
that the standard deviation can be estimated by dividing the range by
5 (or 6), but this is a **very rough** rule because the actual relationship
between the range, call it $G,$ and the standard deviation $S$ depends
heavily on the sample size.

For $n = 27,$ one has $G/4 \approx S.$  And for $n = 100,$ its $G/5 \approx S.$ [Simulations in R below use standard
normal distributions, but the ratio doesn't depend on $\sigma.]$

```
set.seed(2021)
g = replicate(10^5, diff(range(rnorm(27))))
mean(g)
[1] 3.997148  # aprx 4
g = replicate(10^5, diff(range(rnorm(100))))
mean(g)
[1] 5.016428  # aprx 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with R (I use SAS) though I think I see what's going on based off the R documentation I'm looking at. I assume the 10^5 is just a bootstrapping, running the replicate command an arbitrarily large number of times? That would mean that rnorm is creating normal distributions based off of n data points (in this case, 27 or 100), finding the difference between the min and max values for that distribution and repeating that process 10^5 times (and then g(mean) taking the mean of all of those)? Do I have that right? What formula does rnorm use for making normal distributions?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bootstrap. More like a Monte Carlo integration by sampling. // Currently in R, `rnorm` generates a standard normal sample starting with a sample $U \sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ from the well-vetted Mersenne-Twister random number generator. Then it uses the inverse CDF (quantile) method to get $Z = \Phi^{-1}(U),$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal CDF. // Because neither $\Phi$ nor $\Phi^{-1}$ can be expressed in closed form, R uses a rational approx. that is accurate within double-precision. // In earliest releases, R used the Box-Muller method to sample from std norm.